# data scraping from multiple pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Below code works for single page scraping from olx, need help to extract from multiple pages.

```
import requests 
import re 
from django.conf.urls import url, include

url_base = "https://www.olx.in" 
url = url_base + "/hyderabad_g4058526/cars_c5"

info_labels = ("itemDetails","itemPrice", "itemTitle", "item-location") 
info_pattern = r'(?s)(.?)' 
link_pattern = r'(?s)?data-aut-id="itemBox".*?href="([^"]+?)"'

response = requests.get(url) 
cars = list(zip( *(re.findall(info_pattern.format(label), response.text) for label in info_labels), 
   (url_base + path for path in re.findall(link_pattern, response.text)) ))

print(cars) 
with open('cars_olx.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    for item in cars: 
         f.write(u"%s\n" % str(item))
```

Comment: You need to correct formatting. I have tried but you need to check.

Comment: @rnso, you are right, but this code works for single page scraping. I am looking for multiple pages scaping. if you navigate to "https://www.olx.in/hyderabad_g4058526/cars_c5" and the end of the page it says "load more".